# If ${\rm Aut}\, G$ is cyclic, prove that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

I am trying to understand the proof of the following question:

> If automorphisms of $G$ are cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

I found the following answer here [If $G$ is non-Abelian, show that $Aut(G)$ is not cyclic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898050/if-g-is-non-abelian-show-that-autg-is-not-cyclic/1898071#1898071) :

> Suppose that ${\rm Aut}\,(G)$ is cyclic and let $f$ its generator, let $x,y\in G$ such that $y$ does not commute with $yxy^{-1}$, (since $G$ is not commutative, you can find $z$ such that $z$ does not commute with $y$, write $x=y^{-1}zy, yxy^{-1}=z$)  there exists $n$ such that $c_x(z)=xzx^{-1}=f^n, m: c_y(z)=yzy^{-1}=f^m$, this implies that $c_x$ commutes with $c_y$, we deduce that $c_y(c_x(x))=c_x(x))$,  i.e
> $yxy^{-1}=xyxy^{-1}x^{-1}$,  i.e $(yxy^{-1})x=x(yxy^{-1})$ i.e $x$ commutes with $yxy^{-1}$. Contradiction.

But I really do not understand this solution, could someone clarify it for me please?

**EDIT: I am not searching for a proof only, I am searching for an easy proof that do not require previous theorems and I think the above proof do this, so the suggested duplicate does not answer my question, I hope the question is reopened for answers please.**

Comment: This proof doesn't even use the fact that Aut(G) is cyclic. He defines two conjugation automorphisms $c_x$ and $c_y$, they commute so sub $y$ into $c_x\circ c_y=c_y\circ c_x$ to get $xyx^{-1}=yxyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, i.e. $y(xyx^{-1})=(xyx^{-1})y$, true for every $x,y$. Now for any $y,z\in G$, there exist $x\in G$ such that $xyx^{-1}=z$, hence it's commutative.

Comment: The method you posted is not right at all. It deduces by contradiction that $x$ commutes with $yxy^{-1}$, but the original assumption it states is about $y$ instead of $x$

Comment: @copingroidcel are you saying that it is not correct proof?

Comment: No, I was clarifying it like you asked, just rephrased his proof in clearer way. Actually I think there's an error, the last sentence is false, in general conjugation is not transitive. No wonder the cyclicality of Aut(G) is not used.